# Why use Caller information attributes

Tags: logging, .net-4.5, stack-trace, c#-5.0

Is it better to use caller info attributes over the stack trace object?  What are the differences?

Consider the following code that uses caller information attributes for logging.

```
public void Log(
    string message,
    [CallerMemberName] string memberName = null,
    [CallerFilePath] string filePath = null,
    [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
{
    // Do logging.
}
```

From my tests the same result can be achieved using the `StackTrace` class.

```
public void Log(string message)
{
    StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(true);
    StackFrame frame = trace.GetFrame(1);

    string filePath = frame.GetFileName();
    int lineNumber = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
    string memberName = frame.GetMethod().Name;

    // Do logging.
}
```

The only difference I've seen is with anonymous methods, where `StackTrace` includes the generated names of the calling method like `<MyMethod>b_a`.

One thing I don't like about the caller info attributes is that although they do not have to be passed in as arguments, they do have to be defined as method parameters on every method where they are to be used, violating DRY principles.

Comment: That's **exactly** why they added it.  Because using the StackTrace class is both horribly expensive and unreliable.

Comment: How is it unreliable?